# Количество ретвитов\упоминаний адреса страницы

Tags: twitter, api

Есть ли в twitter api метод для того чтобы узнать сколько было ретвитов\упоминаний адреса страницы? 
(Те узнать сколько было твитов и ретвитов http://example.com/)

Comment: Нет, нету

Comment: ну яндекс Share как-то же узнает

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать через метод [search](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets)